# How to "program in binary trees" with Mathematica?

Tags: trees

I want to do the following:

```
f[x_] := If[OddQ[x[[1]]], Nothing, x/2 // Simplify]

A = Table[2 (n + k), {k, 0, 4}]/2
n = 2 n1;
f /@ A
n = 2 n1 + 1;
f /@ A
```

This outputs the following:

```
{n, 1 + n, 2 + n, 3 + n, 4 + n}
{n1, 1 + n1, 2 + n1}
{1 + n1, 2 + n1}
```

That is: It takes the list A, makes a substitution, sieves out whatever has an odd constant. Now I want to do apply the same process to the second and third list, and then to the second and third list of the previous ones, etc. This will yield a binary tree structure but I have no idea how to do that in Mathematica. Can you help me? I'm not sure if the tagging is correct, tho.

---

**EDIT:** I'll write a simpler example that If solved, I could use it to my original problem. Suppose I want to program the following:

> [image]

That is: It starts with $a$, if it moves to the left, it concatenates $a$ on the left and we get $aa$, if it moves to the left, it concatenates $b$ to the left so we get $ab$ and then, we proceed this way and build the tree. Now, I want to store every level of the tree so that I can show it in a graph such as the one in here. I've been thinking and I guess I could make some elementary program to do this but it is possible that Mathematica already has some neat stuff for this?

Comment: What should it do when the constant is zero? If you have the element `n1` then does this get removed, or does it get changed to `n1/2`?

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Nothing. I want "sieve out" odd integers that would appear there.

Comment: Then how does the set become empty?

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Yeah, that was poor hindsight on my part. I tought the set would get empty but when I wrote it on paper, I saw it doesn't. I edited it.

Comment: Okay. I don't fully understand the question, but here are a few tips. (1) You can use `Select` to "sieve out by retention" (that is, keeping only the ones you want). (2) You can use `FixedPoint` to stop the sieving once the set stabilizes. (3) It is not really safe to assume the constant (which might be zero) is found as `x[[1]]`. I recommend instead finding the variable(s) in the list, call them `vars`, and determining whether constant term is odd using e.g. `OddQ[x/.Thread[vars->0]]`.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau See the edit: I've made a simpler problem that if solved, would help me to do that.